# Unpivot in PostgreSQL with null value

Tags: postgresql

I am doing conversion Unpivot  from Oracle to postgres. I am having the following problem: In Oracle Unpivot  automatically removed with null value, but postgres fails.How to make Postgres the same as Oracle Can you help me?

Oracle:

```
with detail as (                
    select          
        'A1' as a,      
        'A2' as b,      
        'A3' as c,      
        null as d       
    from dual           
)               
select * from detail unpivot (              
    agg_value for (agg_name) in (           
        a as 'Max Concurrent Users',        
        b as 'Max Concurrent User Time',        
        c as 'Min Concurrent Users',        
        d as 'Min Concurrent User Time'     
    )           
);
```

Result Oracle:

[image]

Postgres:

```
WITH detail AS (                        
    select                  
        'A1' as a,              
        'A2' as b,              
        'A3' as c,              
        null as d               
)                       
SELECT * FROM (                     
    SELECT 
        unnest(array['Max Concurrent Users', 'Max Concurrent User Time', 'Min Concurrent Users', 'Min Concurrent User Time']) AS agg_name,
        unnest(array[a, b, c, d]) AS agg_value
    FROM
        detail
) foo;
```

Result postgres:

[image]

Comment: Is your spellchecker acting up? You have "Univot" (missing "p") in at least three places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `WHERE` clause as follows: (I have attached the Oracle query, You can use the same `WHERE` clause in the Postgress)

```
WITH DETAIL AS (
    SELECT 'A1' AS A,
           'A2' AS B,
           'A3' AS C,
           NULL AS D
      FROM DUAL
)
SELECT *
  FROM DETAIL UNPIVOT ( AGG_VALUE
    FOR ( AGG_NAME )
IN ( A AS 'Max Concurrent Users',
     B AS 'Max Concurrent User Time',
     C AS 'Min Concurrent Users',
     D AS 'Min Concurrent User Time' ) )
 WHERE AGG_VALUE IS NOT NULL; -- ADD THIS CONDITION
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer a lateral join against a values clause to implement an unpivot in Postgres:

```
WITH detail (a,b,c,d) AS (                        
  values ('A1', 'A2', 'A3', null)
)                       
SELECT u.*
FROM detail d
  cross join lateral (
    values 
        (a, 'Max Concurrent Users'),
        (b, 'Max Concurrent User Time'),
        (c, 'Min Concurrent Users'),
        (d, 'Min Concurrent User Time')
  ) as u (col, col_name)
where u.col is not null;
```

If the column names in the table are "readable" you can simplify this by using JSON:

```
select u.*
from detail d
  cross join jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(d)) as u(col_name, col);
```